# Are clothes part of Skrull physiology?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, skrulls

In many MCU movies and TV shows, whenever a Skrull changes his/her physical appearance, their clothes changes too. Is clothing a part of their physiology and is it referenced in the comics or elsewhere?

Comment: Also, in Secret Invasion, we see that even when Skrulls take their true form (upon injury or death) their clothes remain the same.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### No.

It's not shown in Secret Wars as far as I know but they have access to a form of nanotechnology.

This is evidenced in *Captain Marvel*.

When we first see Talos take the form of the surfer girl his initial clothing is absorbed into a purple gem on his shoulder and new clothing formed from the same source.